# I keep getting a syntaxerror invalid character when doing a Jquery AJAX POST to CFC

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an AJAX POST to a CFC page. The CFC function will actually  update the database. However, I keep getting a "SyntaxError invalid character" error after the function is executed. I am not expecting a response. Here is my Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab5').click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); //This will prevent the form from reloading the page.
        var myname = $("#textField5a").val(); //Value of the form field with ID=myname 

        // AJAX CALL TO COLDFUSION COMPONENT 
        $.ajax({
            url: "autocomplete.cfc?method=doemail", //Put the functions.cfc file in the same directory as the file containing the form.
            type: "post",
            data: { myname: (myname) }, //Values sent to the functions.cfc file
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
                console.log("AJAX call failed");
                console.log(errThrown);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

and here is my cfc page

```
 <cffunction name="doemail" access="remote" output="no" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="myname" required="yes">
           <cfquery name="qryupdatetab" datasource="RADIUS">
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[BusProcDesc]
                   ([BPDID]
                   ,[ProposalID]
                   ,[Purpose]
                   ,[Functions])
             VALUES
                   ('1'
                   ,'1'
                   ,'testing'
                   ,'#arguments.myname#')
        </cfquery>

 </cffunction>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The unclosed document ready is just a typo right?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. Thanks Huangism.

Comment: What are the data types of your table BusProscDesc? Looking at your insert query you are inserting the string '1' into BPDID and ProposalID columns.. These may well need to be integers

Comment: BPDID & ProposalID are both "int", the other two columns are varchar. I removed the ' ' for the 1's and its still getting the error.